# Debug Properly with PyCharm module named io.py

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

It appears that module named io.py (inside some of my packages) can not be debugged in PyCharm (2017.3.1 Community) - breakpoints never hit.
Rename of this module fixed the problem.

The question is: naming a module `io.py` is not recommended in python?

- Or its just a PyCharm feature / bug?
- Is there a known workaround for that?

Thanks

Comment: it's the name of a builtin module..

Comment: I did not mention io.py module is a part of a package.
This seems to be allowed: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html

Comment: You will need to use relative imports to prevent confusion, or just name your module something else.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Pycharm bug - one is free to name their modules anything they want, including io.py.

For a fix in newer versions of Pycharm, locate the file pydevd_dont_trace_files.py. In my case, Pycharm is installed at /opt/pycharm-2020.3, so this file is found at:

/opt/pycharm-2020.3/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_dont_trace_files.py

Locate the line similar to:

```
    if IS_PY3K:
        # if we try to trace io.py it seems it can get halted (see http://bugs.python.org/issue4716)
        DONT_TRACE['io.py'] = LIB_FILE
```

And comment out this DONT_TRACE line and restart Pycharm.

Of course this line must have been put in for a legitimate reason, so I usually uncomment it once I'm done debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can in the python docs to find the `io`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html

`io` is a built-in module:

> The io module provides the Python interfaces to stream handling. Under Python 2.x, this is proposed as an alternative to the built-in file object, but in Python 3.x it is the default interface to access files and streams.

You can not create `.py` file named the built-in modules, they will get repetition.

Comment: I did not mention io.py module is a part of a package.
This seems to be allowed: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html